# Exception in creating webservices from axis2 with tomcat6 server

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I am trying to create a webservice from java application.
I am using tomcat 6 server and axis2 ..i had installed axis2 and set the runtime location for axis2 inside Web services>Axis2 preferences.

This is the exception am getting when am trying to create a webservice..

```
Exception occurred while reading or writing file {0}The Axis2 facets cannot be installed since the Axis2 runtime location has not been set.  
Please go to the Web Services preference page and set the Axis2 runtime location under Axis2 Preferences.
```

Can anyone give a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

If u have set axis 2 preferences properly then i think u have not set the configuration properly while creating the project in eclipse.

Follow the below steps..

In eclipse go to File- New- Dynamic Web Project..

In configuration select custom and modify..

Check the Axis2 Web Services and click OK..

Follow normal steps afterwards.. It should work now....

Comment: thanx..finally i had solved the issue..i had copied the axis2 exploadedwar folder and dependent files from my old workspace location.

Answer (score -1):

Create a **dummy** dynamic webproject with axis2 feature and , 
then try the old project of yours

Go to your services java file and

- right click and choose webservices **-->**
- create webservice  **-->**
- choose webservice runtime to axis2  **-->**
- and continue it should work now